# Regex to identify numbers except when enclosed by "[" "]"

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex such that I only match the first number NOT enclosed by square brackets.

e.g. `asdadsas,*&(*&(*2asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3` should match 2 ( no square brackets )

and `asdadsas,*&(*&(*[2]asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3` should match 3

The regex I have so far is : `(?<!\[)[0-9](?!\])`

However, the problem I have is that `[2` should still match 2.

I only want to skip the number if it has a `[` to the left AND a `]` to the right.

I don't know how ( or if its even possible) to implement this kind of conditional logic in a regex.

Comment: Clarify: will the number be the only thing in the square brackets? If there is a `[2a]` near the beginning of the string should that be skipped or returned?

Comment: hmmm. you know what i did not think of that... I think for the purpose of this question it does not matter. But it would be cool if you could  show both ways :p i.e. if it only works for [2] I will give u the tick :)

Comment: You need to specify the language you are using..java doesn't support quantifier in lookbehind and javascript doesn't support lookbehind at all

Comment: +1 What we have here is a good regex question: The goal is well-stated with examples, OP has made a reasonable attempt (which works for the most part), and the problem is shown (again with example) and clearly explained.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard the only thing missing is which regex engine is missing but still deserves a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
[0-9](?!(?<=\[.)\])
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/0vKy8hyMy0

Explanation: `[0-9]` matches a digit, `(?!(?<=\[.)\])` enforces the requirement that the character before and after that digit are not `[` and `]` respectively.  To break this down, consider the following regex:

```
(?<=\[.)\]
```

This can be read as "match a `]` but only if the character two places ago was a `[`".  By putting this into a negative lookahead just after we match the digit, we can fail if the character two places ago was a `[` and the next character is a `]`.

Comment: If any number of digits was wanted, would `[0-9]+(?!(?<=\[[0-9]+)\])` work?

Comment: Only if variable length lookbehinds were supported, however you may be able to get it to work with a backreference: `([0-9]+)(?!(?<=\[\1)\])`.

Comment: @F.J: This last pattern (for multiple digits) can't work for two reasons. The first is that the regex engine will backtrack before the last digit (ex: `[123]` will give `12` as result). The second is only for engines that don't support variable length lookbehinds: using a backreference doesn't make the subpattern inside the lookbehind less variable.

Comment: You can solve these problems using an alternation: `(?<=\[)\d++(?!])|(?<![\[\d])\d+` or `(?<=\[)\d+(?!\d|])|(?<!\[|\d)\d+`, or using a conditional (PCRE): `(?(?<=\[)\d++(?!])|(?<!\d)\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Regex only solution would be an overkill

Simply use `(^|\D)(\d+)($|\D)` and then select the first that matches your criteria..

In c#,you can do it this way

```
string output=Regex.Matches(input,@"(^|\D)(\d+)(\D|$)")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Where(x=>!(x.Value.StartsWith("[")&& x.Value.EndsWith("]")))
                   .First()
                   .Groups[2]
                   .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!    # start negative lookahead
    \[ # open bracket
    \d # digit (use \d+ if needed)
    \] # close bracket
)      # end negative lookahead
\[     # literal bracket
(\d)   # capture digit
|      # alternation (OR)
(?<!   # start negative lookbehind
\[     # literal bracket
)
(\d)   # capture digit
```

This will capture the digits as back references.  If you need the digit to be the full match, you can probably use a lookahead.

http://rubular.com/r/C8YSRiY1d0

Answer (score 0):

Try using look-arounds and alternation. This matches either a digit not preceded by `[` or a digit not followed by `]`:

```
(?<!\[)\d|\d(?!\])
```

In order for it to work with numbers of more than one digit, you'd need to add look-arounds to ensure the previous/next character is neither a bracket nor a digit:

```
(?<!\[|\d)\d+|\d+(?!\]|\d)
```

viz. (using Ruby; should work similarly elsewhere):

```
>> rex = /(?<!\[|\d)\d+|\d+(?!\]|\d)/
>> "&(*25asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3".match rex #=> #<MatchData "25">
>> "&(*[25asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3".match rex #=> #<MatchData "25">
>> "&(*25]asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3".match rex #=> #<MatchData "25">
```

but

```
>> "&(*[25]asdasd*U(*&*()&(*3".match rex #=> #<MatchData "3">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe simplest regex that should for you is:

```
(?<!\[)[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?!\])
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/xWXFg7QXZJ